# data insert in mysql using php

Tags: php

I am creating a signup system and this code is working but when I insert more than three fields it is not inserting the data. In this code its inserting into fields *name*, *fname*, and *email*, but no values are being inserted for other columns. Why is this happening?

```
<?php

$name=$_POST["name"]; 
$fname=$_POST["fname"]; 
$email=$_POST["email"]; 
$gender=$_POST["gender"]; 
$password=$_GET["password"]; 



$query="INSERT INTO  student(name,fname,email,password) VALUES ('".$name."','".$fname."','".$email."','".$password."')"; 

$url="localhost"; 
$user="root"; 
$pass=""; 
$db="sms"; 

$connection=new mysqli($url,$user,$pass,$db); 
$connection->query($query); 
header("Location: index1.php")

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Try giving `name` like this to all fields

Comment: hash your $password, do not store directly. and why $_GET in password.

Comment: Additionally you are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your query.

Comment: using $_post your are getting gender...but it is not in query... & if password is also posted from any form then get it also in $_POST['password']...

Comment: Why using $_GET['password']. It is most confidential data in your application.

Comment: check the datatypes of `gender` and `password`.

Comment: please post your form here

Comment: i have used this code but its not working and also i have add columns but not giving result

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying with more than three fields then also check in database table. Make sure with adding more columns must add those columns in database table also. And also there is suggestion of making password field more secure. 
Please try with following code.

```
<?php

$name=$_POST["name"]; 
$fname=$_POST["fname"]; 
$email=$_POST["email"]; 
$gender=$_POST["gender"]; 
$password=md5($_POST["password"]); 



$query="INSERT INTO student(name,fname,email,gender,password) VALUES('".$name."','".$fname."','".$email."','".$gender."','".$password."')"; 

$url="localhost"; 
$user="root"; 
$pass=""; 
$db="sms"; 

$connection=new mysqli($url,$user,$pass,$db); 
$connection->query($query); 
header("Location: index1.php");

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your variable is string, php get this as a string so use this as;

```
$query="INSERT INTO  student(name,fname,email,password) VALUES ("'".$name."'","'".$fname."'","'".$email."'","'".$password."'")";
```

add double quotation mark to encapsulate the single quotation mark.

Comment: thanks its working but has little problem,its not showing password

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $name    = $_POST["name"]; 
    $fname   = $_POST["fname"]; 
    $email   = $_POST["email"]; 
    $gender  = $_POST["gender"]; 
    $password= $_POST["password"]; 

    $query   = "INSERT INTO  student(name,fname,email,password) VALUES ('".$name."','".$fname."','".$email."','".$password."')"; 

    $url     = "localhost"; 
    $user    = "root"; 
    $pass    = ""; 
    $db      = "sms"; 

    $connection = new mysqli($url,$user,$pass,$db); 
    $connection->query($query); 
    header("Location: index1.php")
?>
```

Comment: Why negative ? Can you mention the reason ?